# .htaccess with url shortener

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, seo, friendly-url

I've made a url shortener app , but can't seem to work my way around .htaccess to indeed make the urls shorter.
(I'm using xampp)

my domain is http://localhost/smd
i would like the user to be able to add a 7 digit code after smd http://localhost/smd/code
and redirect them to their page
my current .htaccess code is like that:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9_{7}]*$ redirect.php?shortened=$1  [L]
```

which redirects the user to to a another page in my smd directory instead of  the correct one.
Thanks in advance!

my redirect file:

```
    <?php

include_once './class/Short.php';
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Athens');

if(isset($_GET['shortened'])) {
    $short = new Short();
    $code = $_GET['shortened'];
    $short->shortened = $code;
    
    $short->getOneUrlByShort();
    
     $expire = $short->getExpiryFromShortened($code);
    
     $comp = (date('Y-m-d H:i:s')<=$expire['expiry_date']);
    $enabled = $short->is_enabled;

    if ($url = $short->getUrl($code) And $comp And $enabled == 1) {

        $redirect = $url['original'];
        header("Refresh: 3;".$redirect);
        die();
    }else if($url = $short->getUrl($code) And !$comp And $short->renewable == 1 And $enabled == 1){
        session_start();
        
        $short->renewable = 0;
        $newRenewVal = $short->renewable;
        
        $newExpiration = strtotime('+'.$short->active_period.' minutes');
        $formattedExpi = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $newExpiration);
        
        $original = $url['original'];
        $_SESSION['original'] = $original;
        $_SESSION['expiration_date'] = $formattedExpi;
        

        $short->renewUrl($code, $formattedExpi, $newRenewVal);

       
        header('Location: http://localhost/smd/expiredAndRenew.php');
    }else {
        header('Location: http://localhost/smd/urlExpired.php');
    }

}



  ?>
```

My current directory looks like that [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vx0No.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for sharing your efforts. Could you please post samples of URLs eg--> FROM which url TO which url you want to rewrite? Just sample urls should be fine, let us know, it will give us better understanding of your question, cheers.

Comment: What is the contents of `redirect.php`? Because that's where the actual redirect takes place. Does it read the URL from the database based on the shortened param, then insert it into `header("Location: $url");`? If not, why not? (I'm also pretty sure you need to wrap the square brackets in your RegEx in parens in order to actually get $1)

Comment: i want to shorten something like that  http://localhost/smd/redirect.php?shortened=EtBVwUI to http://localhost/smd/EtBVwUI .

Comment: In that case it's not really a URL shortener (which is where you post arbitrary long URLs from other websites), it's just simple rewriting to get SEO friendly URLs. Which means you can ignore my comment except the last part about needing `^([a-zA-Z0-9_{7}])*$`

Comment: Please post code, not images of code. You need to do some basic debugging. Use something like `var_dump($_GET); die();` to check the url rewriting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples could you please try following. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. Also this simply grabs everything coming after `smd`(with ignorecase emabled) in uri and passes it to your redirect.php as query string. In case you are looking for specific string/match for text after smd then kindly do let us know more clearly on that part.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]{7})/?$ redirect.php?shortened=$1 [L]
```

Comment: IT WORKED THANKS SOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO MUCH !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! @RavinderSingh13 csan you add the regex as well?

Comment: @ΝίκοςΠαπαδάκος, AWESOME, very happy to help here :)

Comment: it works but i need it to be exactly 7  chars

Comment: @ΝίκοςΠαπαδάκος, I think I am feeling sleepy now :) try `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]{7})/?$ redirect.php?shortened=$1 [L]` this one once and let me know?

Comment: Ok i fixed it ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_{7}]*)/?$

Comment: @ΝίκοςΠαπαδάκος, no I believe that `{7}` should be outside of `]` try mine previous comment one that should work fine.

Comment: Thanks very much man I am really sorry to bother you like that Hope you have a great night!

Comment: @ΝίκοςΠαπαδάκος, your welcome, np, cheers and keep sharing and keep posting good q & a on this great site, cheers, happy learning.